# Should "datamodel", "data-modeling", and "data-model" be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

Should [datamodel](/questions/tagged/datamodel), [data-modeling](/questions/tagged/data-modeling), and [data-model](/questions/tagged/data-model) be synonyms?

They all seem to have similar related tags.

[data-model](/questions/tagged/data-model) has no wiki summary and only 31 questions, so should probably be subsumed into [datamodel](/questions/tagged/datamodel) at least.

PS I don't have authority to change them all, so someone else would need to.

Comment: Sure. But don't touch my [tag:date-a-model]!

Comment: You have me scared for a moment there @Andrew.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards At least I know what to name any API I might invent.